# Get partial object list from JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net

I am calling a RESTful service in C# and the result is similar to this:

```
{
  "blabla":1,
  "bbb":false,
  "blabla2":{
    "aaa":25,
    "bbb":25,
    "ccc":0
  },
  "I_want_child_list_from_this":{
     "total":15226,
     "max_score":1.0,
     "I_want_this":[
       {
        "A":"val1",
        "B":"val2",
        "C":"val3"
       },
       {
        "A":"val1",
        "B":"val2",
        "C":"val3"
       }
       ...
      ]
  "more_blabla": "fff"
  ... 
}
```

I want to get the "I_want_this" part as a `list` of `object` or `JObject`
Is there something like

```
(JObject)responseString["I_want_child_list_from_this"]["I_want_this"]
```

more generically:

```
(JObject)responseString["sub"]["sub_sub"]
```

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json`

Thanks!

Comment: Which JSON parser are you using? Newtonsoft?

Comment: Yes, using `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: look at e.g. here http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

Comment: Thanks @Gomes Your comment took me closer to my current solution. You can make it an answer and I accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @DDan done as per your request, i am happy if it is solves your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below link is appears to be close to the solution as the requester using NewtonSoft.Json as his api to manipulate the object. Appreciate the solutions from other users as well.

look at e.g. here newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

Comment: Can you summarize the information here? Link-only answers are prone to breakage and sometimes even flagging and deletion.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I would create a class that represents the JSON structure returned from the service call. (http://json2csharp.com/ great utility for auto-generating classes from JSON)

Second, if you are not using Newtonsoft.Json library, I would recommending grabbing that library.

Lastly, use Newtonsoft to deserialize the JSON from the service call into the class you created:

```
var json = Service.GetJson();
var yourDesiralizedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourJsonToCSharpClass>(json);
var listYouWant = yourDesiralizedJson.IWantChildList.IWantThis;
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks ideal, however I don't have a common structure for the result type, that's why I am expecting `object`s or `JObject`s

Answer (score 1):

The best solution (imo) is to define classes that describe your JSON schema then use `DeserializeObject`, as suggested by ertdiddy. As a shortcut, you can use `DeserializeAnonymousType` with incomplete definitions of your schema, taking advantage of JSON's leniency.  In your case, this code is working for me:

```
        var testDataFromQuestion = @"
{
  ""blabla"":1,
  ""bbb"":false,
  ""blabla2"":{
    ""aaa"":25,
    ""bbb"":25,
    ""ccc"":0
  },
  ""I_want_child_list_from_this"":{
     ""total"":15226,
     ""max_score"":1.0,
     ""I_want_this"":[
       {
        ""A"":""val1"",
        ""B"":""val2"",
        ""C"":""val3""
       },
       {
        ""A"":""val1"",
        ""B"":""val2"",
        ""C"":""val3""
       }
      ],
  ""more_blabla"": ""fff""
}";

        var anonymousDefinitionOfJson = new {
           I_want_child_list_from_this = new {
               I_want_this = new Dictionary<string, string>[] {}
           }
        };
        var fullDeserializationOfTestData =
           JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(testDataFromQuestion,
                                                anonymousDefinitionOfJson);
        var stuffYouWant = insterestingBits.I_want_child_list_from_this.I_want_this;
        Console.WriteLine($"The first thing I want is {stuffYouWant[0]["A"]}");
```

This outputs the expected value "val1". I'm anonymously defining the minimal classes that get just the data you want, then I'm asking Newtonsoft to parse just enough to populate those classes.